# How to determine whether the rational maps are dominant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I determine whether the following rational maps are dominant or not?
(our field is just some algebraically closed field)

(a) $\varphi_2: \mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1, x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$;
(b) $\varphi_3: \mathbb{A}^2 \cdots \mathbb{A}^1,\left(x_1, x_2\right) \mapsto \frac{1}{x_1 x_2}$;

So a rational map is dominant if the image is dense (Zariski topology). Now since our field is arbitrary and not something familiar like complex numbers and our topology is also a bit strange, I am having a hard time thinking of how to show the closure is the entire space.

Comment: Regarding (a): Let $y\in k$ ($k$ is the algebraically closed field). Then $y$ is in the image of $\varphi_2$ if there exists $x\in k$ such that $\frac{1}{x} = y \in k$. This is equivalent to $\exists x\in k:xy = 1$, which is true if and only if $y\neq 0$. Hence the image is $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus 0$.

Comment: @Bill: Note that any Zariski-closed subset of $\mathbb A^1$ is the set of common zeros of some number of polynomials. Since any polynomial has finitely many roots, any proper closed subset of $\mathbb A^1$ is finite. And the set $\mathbb A^1\backslash\{0\}$ is infinite (because any algebraically closed field is infinite), hence its closure is the whole $\mathbb A^1$.

Comment: @danneks , thanks!